# style multiple textviews at activity level

Tags: android, android-resources

We have multiple textview wights in a GridView nested in a RelativeLayout The textviews have these id's tv1 tv2 ect From here I have multiple layouts for various screen sizes sw400dp sw360dp ect What we would like to accomplish is problematically use one style for the odd numbered tv1 and a different style for tv2 This app has multiple activities. Is this possible might be the best question Next how do I distinguish the odd from even in the Manifest. I am only changing the width the font size only changes from one layout to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@James_Duh thanks for the answer but I have a better idea What I did was create two Styles theOdd and theEven making the background color the desired color for each row of TextViews then rather tan apply these in the Manifest file I attached the correct STYLE to the corresponding TextView in the Activity XML file with this line of code

```
style="@style/theOdd" or style="@style/theEven"
```

I doubt I can up-vote my answer but it offers more elegance and less code

Answer (score 1):

@user2475470 Nesting your 9 row GridView with 18 TextView could be reduced to just 9 TextView widgets this would make for a little lighter code in the application but this is not an exact answer to your question. You might look at posts that naming widgets in the Manifest

Comment: I like the idea of not nesting the TextView widgets it does lessen the amount of code. Still trying to understand how to do this at the activity level or use Themes with the styles the use of the parent in styles is  way confusing. Too use to CSS

Comment: I found this link that describes what you want to do it should clear up the naming with parent http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-styles-and-themes-tutorial-with-multiple-style-inheritance-examples